# After Effects event handler gets terminated in mid-execution

Tags: javascript, extendscript, after-effects

Consider the following After Effects script:

```
var window = new Window('dialog');
var edit1 = window.add('EditText { characters: 20, active: true }');
var edit2 = window.add('EditText { characters: 20 }');
edit1.onChange = edit2.onChange = function() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        $.writeln(i);
    }
}
window.show();
```

*The following works correctly:* The script creates a modal dialog with two text input fields. Whenever I edit the text in either of the fields, then leave it (via tab), the `onChange` handler gets executed and prints the numbers 1..100 to the console. Note that `onChange` is only raised when a modified text field loses focus, not immediately after each key stroke.

*Here's the problem:* If I edit one of the text fields, then immediately press the Esc key, the dialog gets closed. While closing, the text field loses focus, so its `onChange` handler gets executed. However, its execution gets terminated after just a few instructions. It usually manages to print the numbers 1..7 or 1..10, then just stops and the debugger tells me that the script execution is finished.

My guess is that this is some sort of garbage collection issue: Once the window disappears, it gets GC'd, along with its running event handlers.

How do I keep After Effects from silently terminating my event handler?

Comment: I found a workaround: By subscribing to onChanging rather than onChange, I get notified immediately for each key stroke, so by the time the user presses Esc to close the window, there is nothing left to do. Not my favorite solution, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can set OnClose event as following:

```
function fnc(){
    for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        $.writeln(i);
    }
}
edit1.onChange = edit2.onChange = function(){
   fnc();
}

window.onClose = function(){
    edit1.onChange = edit2.onChange = null;
    fnc();
}
```

Comment: That's a clever idea, but it doesn't work for me. When I close the window by pressing the Esc key, the window's onClose handler gets prematurely terminated, too. So the result is the same.